# Use interface inheritance or just implement all the interfaces directly?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, interface

I don't necessarily see a grandiose benefit of interfaces inheriting interfaces.

Consider the following three interfaces, the third inheriting the other two

```
interface IOne {
}

interface ITwo {
}

// interface inheritance
interface IAll : IOne, ITwo {
}
```

Is it best to

```
class C : IOne, ITwo { ... }
```

or

```
class C : IAll { ... }
```

If the latter can be beneficial then why not just create IAll to have all the methods of both IOne and ITwo without inheriting from them? After all it's an interface.

Is interface inheritance practical, not just useful?

Comment: Maybe if you have a huge number of interfaces you're inheriting from, you can use this trick to shorten the line length. Otherwise, it seems to me like needless obfuscation (unless two interfaces can be naturally grouped together).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A good way to think about interface "inheritance" is to forget entirely that it is called "inheritance".  After all, clearly the "base" interface contributes no *functionality* to the "derived" interface; all it contributes is the promise that there will be certain members.

A class derivation relationship usually implies an "is-a-kind-of" relationship. A NullReferenceException is-a-kind-of Exception.  An interface derivation relationship doesn't imply that at all -- it makes very little sense to say that `IEnumerable<T>` is a kind of `IDisposable`.

Rather, interface inheritance means "a type which implements `IEnumerable<T>` is required to also implement `IDisposable`. That is, interface inheritance does not mean "this is a kind of that", but rather "every implementation of this is required to also implement that".

Does that make it more compelling?

Comment: That's a very useful wording that I will try to remember :)

Comment: But how about `interface IList<T> : ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, ...;` ?  Every IList<T> IS-A ICollection<T>, right? The substitution principle seems to hold.

Comment: @Henk: But there is no "is a" relationship with ICollection in the first place. ICollection is an interface; it represents a "can do" relationship, not an "is a kind of" relationship.  Interface inheritance means "anything that can do the functions of a list must also provide the functions of a collection and a sequence".

Comment: not to drag it out too long, But if X can do anything that Y can do, then X "is a kind of" Y in my opinion. Especially when "can do" is all there is to X and Y, as is the case with interfaces. At the class/interface boundary I've always regarded this as 2 non-conflicting points of view, _FileStream implements IDisposable_ and _List<> inherits from IList<>_ are both useful, productive concepts.

Comment: If interface X inherits interface Y, then X is *SUBSTITUTABLE* for Y, which is a key aspect of an IS-A relationship.

Answer (score 2):

Do what is semantically correct.  Don't do something just to save typing in an extra interface.

If 'IAll' is a concept that has meaning in your program, fine, use it.  If it's just a way of not typing 'IFirst, ISecond', don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

There might be methods which want an `IAll` argument -- so if you meet the requirements to implement the whole of `IAll`, it's convenient to do so, rather than just implement each of the interfaces it extends!

Normally, of course, interfaces aren't empty, so there's a specific (maybe small) cost in implementing one and/or the other (different, multiple methods will need to get implemented).  If, say, `IFirst` has a method `foo`, and `ISecond` has a method `bar`, it makes perfect sense to extend both into an `IBoth` even if that doesn't add further needed methods -- it allows a method to clearly express that it needs an argument that has **both** methods, `foo` **and** `bar`.

If every interface in the world was empty, their very use (much less extending them with further empty interface) would be **much** more dubious of course!-)

Comment: I would suggest that if the purpose one is using an interface to aggregate others (e.g. `IOne` and `ITwo`) it may be good idea to explicitly specify that the class implements all three interfaces unless the name of the aggregating class would make it obvious (e.g. if interfaces had been named `IFoo`, `IBar`, and `IFooAndBar`, the latter name would suggest that a class which implements `IFooAndBar` implements both `IFoo` and `IBar`).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, interface inheritance is practical. The idea behind interfaces is that a single interface defines a loose "contract" describing a specific set of functionality. This allows a very clean separation of functionality.

Typically, a class that needs to implement multiple interfaces does so by listing each of the interfaces separately, like:

`class C : IOne, ITwo { ... }`

If you need the ability to aggregate the functionality from multiple interfaces then you would want to create a single interface that inherits from the others (like your `IAll` interface). Although you can do this, you generally don't need (or want) to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with first approach, it is much clearer to me. Second one seems contrived, IMO.